# In PingFed, how can I rebuild my setup on local so that my properties files that I have imported in take into effect?

Tags: pingfederate

My PingFed has a connection to a SSO page. That page doesn't have the verbiage I want even though I changed and replaced the properties files. How can I rebuild so that it works?

Comment: There's not enough of a question or explanation of issue here to help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andrew K's comment above, but my guess here is that your updated messages are not being used because you either need to restart PingFederate or disable caching of the message properties files.

For more details, see the tip at the bottom of this page (**cache-language-pack-messages** setting in **<pf_install>/pingfederate/server/default/data/config-store/locale-options.xml**): https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-101/page/ujv1564002982909.html